# Change color in canvas Android

Tags: android

I have a problem. The objective is draw strokes in canvas and get it, but when I make doubleTap the stroke that I have drawn take the color that I choose and I don't that I want that the color of the first stroke still the same e the second stroke another color.

Here my code:

```
package com.example.guiao_2_1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewView extends View implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();
    private DrawingPath newPath;
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
     private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
     private DrawingPath oldPath;
     private ArrayList<DrawingPath> olds = new ArrayList<DrawingPath>();
     private ArrayList<DrawingPath> news = new ArrayList<DrawingPath>();

    public NewView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        for (DrawingPath p : olds){
            paint.setColor(p.color); 
            paint.setStrokeWidth(p.width);
            canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
        }

        for (DrawingPath j : news){
            paint.setColor(j.color); 
            paint.setStrokeWidth(j.width);
            canvas.drawPath(j, paint);
        }
        //canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // nothing to do
                break;
        default:
            return false;
        }

        // Schedules a repaint.
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

        float width = paint.getStrokeWidth();
        int color = paint.getColor();

        oldPath = new DrawingPath(width, color);
        olds.add(oldPath);

        newPath = new DrawingPath(8, Color.GREEN);
        news.add(newPath);



        //int numColor = paint.getColor();
        //String color = Integer.toHexString(numColor);
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), color, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: " + e.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: " + event.toString());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    private class DrawingPath extends Path {

        public float width;
        public int color;

        public DrawingPath(float w, int c){
            width = w;
            color = c;
        }

    }
}
```

Please tell me what I'm doing rong, please.

Answer (score 0):

You never assign your path to your ArrayLists. You just extend your `path`over and over again and paint it with `paint`which gets modified after a Double Tap. Your `òlds`and`news`` has Paths in it with zero Points, therefore these never get painted.

You should make `path`of Type `DrawingPath` and add it to your `ArrayLists` in the corresponding Methods.

```
package com.example.guiao_2_1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewView extends View implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
        GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
    private Paint oldsPaint = new Paint();
    private Paint newsPaint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();
    private Path newPath;
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
    private Path oldPath;
    private ArrayList<Path> olds = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private ArrayList<Path> news = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private boolean hasDoubleTapped;

    public NewView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        oldsPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        oldsPaint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
        oldsPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        oldsPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        oldsPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

        newsPaint.set(oldsPaint);
        newsPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        newsPaint.setStrokeWidth(8f);

        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (hasDoubleTapped) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, oldsPaint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawPath(path, newsPaint);
        }

        for (Path p : olds) {

            canvas.drawPath(p, oldsPaint);
        }

        for (Path j : news) {

            canvas.drawPath(j, newsPaint);
        }
        // canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (hasDoubleTapped) {
                news.add(path);
            } else {
                olds.add(path);
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }

        // Schedules a repaint.
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        hasDoubleTapped = true;

        // int numColor = paint.getColor();
        // String color = Integer.toHexString(numColor);
        // Toast.makeText(getContext(), color, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: " + e.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: " + event.toString());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I have done now is: I removed the Class DrawingPath since it was useless. Then I added a little bit of logic to the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:` case to add the path to the array what you have never done so far. Also I added a extra `Paint` to avoid the need of a derived DrawingPath.

Please look that you really understand what now happens in the Lines `83ff` and `48ff`

Comment: The objective is draw with different colors. For example, at the beginning before you double tap you draw a line and the color is black. When you double tap you change the color to green, but did not want changes to green the line before, but keep the previous color. And in my code when I double tap changes to green what I have drawn.

Comment: I now added the code. I can't test it but it should work. If not, just mention what happens.